# How to set the NameClaimType in an application using OWIN security middleware

Tags: c#, owin

I have created an OWIN web application that is using OpenId Connect for authentication via `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect`.

While authentication works, I find that the created ClaimsIdentity.Name member is null.  It appears the ClaimsIdentity is expecting the name to be provided in the claim:

> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name

However, Thinktecture IdentityServer v3 provides the name as just:

> name

[I find this is configurable via `NameClaimType` in older ASP.Net applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20106605/how-to-set-the-nameclaimtype-in-an-asp-net-mvc-5-site) but it is not clear how I do this with OWIN.

How can I configure which claim is mapped to ClaimsIdentity.Name when using OWIN?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Digging through the code I find this can be configured on the `TokenValidationParameters` object using `NameClaimType` or `NameClaimTypeRetriever` (if the claim type is not fixed).

`TokenValidationParameters` lives on the options object when configuring the middleware.  The following changes to the configuration works in the described case,

```cs
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
        <existing configuration snipped>,
        TokenValidationParameters =
            {
            NameClaimType = Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Name
            }
        } );
```

`Thinktecture.IdentityServer.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Name` is `name`.  A different value can be provided to indicate a different claim should be used.